# Skyblocks Animals

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Skyblock in Minecraft, and I can't get animals to spawn. It is on level 64 in a beach biome, all grass, all light up, and nothing will spawn. The grass area is 16x16, so 1 chunk. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind adding some pictures of your setup? This could include an F3 screen open.

Comment: How long have you waited? If it hasn't been long, this is normal.

Comment: Beach biome with grass? Wait. First off, is there even a beach biome?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493, there is a [Beach Biome](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Biome#Beach). Also, animals do not spawn on beaches, just like the Ocean biome.

Comment: @darkmajik20, have you tried moving away from that patch of grass? ie. about 30 blocks; the same principle for hostile mobs (except without dark places)

Comment: @aytimothy Ohhh. Missed that.

Answer (score 2):

animals don't spawn on beaches, try finding a differend biome basicly anything in the overworld that is not related to ocean will do. also make shure the [temprature](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome#Biome_types) is not above 1

Comment: Thanks guys, i dont have another biome except ocean and desert, but thanks for the help

Comment: thick the answer if you think it helped you